# Google gadget/spreadsheet: Grab spreadsheet key for gadget

Tags: google-apps-script, key, google-docs, feed, google-gadget

So I'm working on a [google gadget](http://rampion.github.com/4eCharSheet/embedded.xml)(really only gadgetizing so I can get a datastore for [this](http://rampion.github.com/4eCharSheet/?#create)) that I want to be embeddable in a google spreadsheet (after this point, I'm going to skip the word google - you can just imagine it's there).

I want to use the spreadsheet that I embed the gadget in as a key/value store for the data I enter within the gadget (I think the 2K limit for gadget data won't be enough).  It looks like what I'll want to do is use the [gadget's feed api](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/remote-content.html#Fetch_Feed) to manipulate the 
[spreadsheet's list feed](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#ListFeeds).  However, in order to know what the spreadsheet's list feed is, I need to know the key for the spreadsheet (which is in the URL).  I don't think I can scrape the key directly from the URL, since the gadget seems to be inserted via iframe.

So I need to know how I can tell a gadget that I'm embedding in a spreadsheet the key for that spreadsheet.  I suppose I could have the user enter it manually, but I'd much rather have my gadget know the key programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using Google Apps Script instead of a gadget. It is aware of the spreadsheet it is embedded on.

http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to retrieve a list of spreadsheets by making a GET request to this URL:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full

See Google Spreadsheets API for more details:
http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#ListingSpreadsheets

Comment: Ok, buy how can I *programmatically* figure out which of those I'm embedded in?  Or is presenting a list if spreadsheets to the user the best I can do?

Comment: Does this help: http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/class_spreadsheet.html#getId

Browser.msgBox(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());

Comment: Any idea about what is url for private domain spreadsheet list ?